# How to handle specific errors in clojure

Tags: clojure, quil

I am using clojure with the quil library, at one point in the code I load a random image in a folder, occasionally I get an error which says:

```
    Could not find a method to load ./data/images/367-014.jpg%3F0
```

How could I make it so that the code keeps on running if it finds this error?

Comment: could you include DM example of a file name that fails to load along with the operative part of the loading code

Comment: Just guessing the "%3F0" part could be causing the file to be not found

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have no way to otherwise prevent the error you are probably looking for try/catch.  (but this question is way underspecified)

see:

http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/1.2.0/clojure.core/try